Load network/security extension in macOS. finish callback is skipped
i'm working on an endpoint security extension loader and implement several callbacks from delegate object OSSystemExtensionRequestDelegate
the callback i'm interested in is :
public func request(_ request: OSSystemExtensionRequest, 
                    didFinishWithResult result: OSSystemExtensionRequest.Result);

public func requestNeedsUserApproval(_ request: OSSystemExtensionRequest);

I've noticed that if I manually approve the extension long time after it was activated, the extension process goes up, but the callback isn't being called. The requestNeedUserApproval callback always gets called.
I see in the unified logs that when the extension goes from
activated_waiting_for_user -> activated_enabling -> activated_enabled

Than the request callback doesn't get called. But whenever the extension goes
activated_waiting_for_user -> activated_disabled

The request callback gets called. (this is counter intuitive since we expected the state activated_disabled may hint that the extension failed to be activated somehow)
Any Idea why my callback doesn't gets called if the extension gets approved long after it was activated ?
